# Count vowels from raw input

Tags: python, string, count

I have a homework question which asks to read a string through raw input and count how many vowels are in the string. This is what I have so far but I have encountered a problem:

```
def vowels():
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    count = 0
    string = raw_input ("Enter a string: ")
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[i] == vowels[i]:
            count = count+1
    print count

vowels()
```

It counts the vowels fine, but due to `if string[i] == vowels[i]:`, it will only count one vowel once as `i` keeps increasing in the range. How can I change this code to check the inputted string for vowels without encountering this problem?

Comment: How about an inner loop to go over your list of vowels?

Comment: @gtgaxiola How exactly do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### `in` operator

You probably want to use the `in` operator instead of the `==` operator - the `in` operator lets you check to see if a particular item is in a sequence/set.

```
1 in [1,2,3] # True
1 in [2,3,4] # False
'a' in ['a','e','i','o','u'] # True
'a' in 'aeiou' # Also True
```

---

Some other comments:

### Sets

The `in` operator is most efficient when used with a `set`, which is a data type specifically designed to be quick for "is item X part of this set of items" kind of operations.*

```
vowels = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
```

**`dict`s are also efficient with `in`, which checks to see if a key exists in the dict.*

### Iterating on strings

A string is a sequence type in Python, which means that you don't need to go to all of the effort of getting the length and then using indices - you can just iterate over the string and you'll get each character in turn:

E.g.:

```
for character in my_string:
    if character in vowels:
        # ...
```

### Initializing a set with a string

Above, you may have noticed that creating a set with pre-set values (at least in Python 2.x) involves using a list. This is because the `set()` type constructor takes a sequence of items. You may also notice that in the previous section, I mentioned that strings are sequences in Python - sequences of characters.

What this means is that if you want a *set* of characters, you can actually just pass a string of those characters to the `set()` constructor - you don't need to have a list one single-character strings. In other words, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
set_from_string = set('aeiou')
set_from_list = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
```

Neat, huh? :) Do note, however, that this can also bite you if you're trying to make a set of *strings*, rather than a set of *characters*. For instance, the following two lines are *not* the same:

```
set_with_one_string = set(['cat'])
set_with_three_characters = set('cat')
```

The former is a set with one element:

```
'cat' in set_with_one_string # True
'c' in set_with_one_string # False
```

Whereas the latter is a set with three elements (each one a character):

```
'c' in set_with_three_characters` # True
'cat' in set_with_three_characters # False
```

### Case sensitivity

Comparing characters is case sensitive. `'a' == 'A'` is False, as is `'A' in 'aeiou'`. To get around this, you can transform your input to match the case of what you're comparing against:

```
lowercase_string = input_string.lower()
```

Comment: Oh wow I think this did it. Thanks for that bit of information it will definitely come in handy.

Comment: Agreed, quite an explanation! +1

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify this code:

```
def vowels():
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    count = 0
    string = raw_input ("Enter a string: ")
    for i in string:
        if i in vowels:
            count += 1
    print count
```

Strings are iterable in Python.

Comment: also, (nitpick), `count += 1`

Comment: TIMTOWTDI - There Is More Than One Way To Do It :)

Comment: But, "There should be one – and preferably only one – obvious way to do it."

Comment: @nneonneo This is true, I just thought I would throw in my favorite Perl idiom.

Comment: No need to use `vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]`. `vowels = 'aeiou'` works just fine. Also, convert your string to lowercase first.

Comment: @Blender I was going off of the original code. I can change that.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    if string[i] == vowels[i]:
```

This actually has a subtler problem than only counting each vowel once - it actually only tests if the first letter of the string is exactly `a`, if the second is exactly `e` and so on.. until you get past the fifth. It will try to test `string[5] == vowels[5]` - which gives an error.

You don't want to use `i` to look into `vowels`, you want a nested loop with a second index that will make sense for `vowels` - eg,

```
for i in range(len(string)):
   for j in range(len(vowels)):
       if string[i] == vowels[j]:
          count += 1
```

This can be simplified further by realising that, in Python, you very rarely want to iterate over the *indexes* into a sequence - the `for` loop knows how to iterate over everything that you can do `string[0]`, `string[1]` and so on, giving:

```
for s in string:
   for v in vowels:
      if s == v:
        count += 1
```

The inner loop can be simplified using the `in` operation on lists - it does exactly the same thing as this code, but it keeps your code's logic at a higher level (what you want to do vs. how to do it):

```
for s in string:
   if s in vowels:
       count += 1
```

Now, it turns out that Python lets do math with booleans (which is what `s in vowels` gives you) and ints - `True` behaves as `1`, `False` as `0`, so `True + True + False` is `2`. This leads to a one liner using a generator expression and sum:

```
sum(s in vowels for s in string)
```

Which reads as 'for every character in `string`, count how many are in `vowels`'.

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter for a one liner

```
print len(filter(lambda ch:ch.lower() in "aeiou","This is a String"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more condensed version using `sum` with a generator:

```
def vowels():
    string = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
    print sum(1 for x in string if x.lower() in 'aeiou')

vowels()
```

Comment: You can sum bools directly (bool subclasses int) - `sum(x.lower() in 'aeiou' for x in string)`.

Answer (score 0):

Option on a theme

```
Mystring = "The lazy DOG jumped Over"
Usestring = ""
count=0
for i in Mystring:
    if i.lower() in 'aeiou':
        count +=1
        Usestring +='^'
    else:
        Usestring +=' '

print (Mystring+'\n'+Usestring)
print ('Vowels =',count)

The lazy DOG jumped Over
  ^  ^    ^   ^  ^  ^ ^ 
Vowels = 7
```